# Change Color of Material-UI TextField when out of focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have this TextField below which works as intended and I want to change the color of the label when it is out of focus, because when it is currently out of focus, it remains black.

Could anyone guide me how can i achieve this?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textField: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  cssLabel: {
    color: "white"
  },
  cssOutlinedInput: {
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: `white !important`
    }
  },
  cssFocused: { color: "white !important" },

  notchedOutline: {
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderColor: "white !important"
  }
}));

<TextField
  id="username"
  label="Username"
  className={classes.textField}
  variant="outlined"
  required={true}
  InputLabelProps={{
    classes: {
      root: classes.cssLabel,
      focused: classes.cssFocused
    }
  }}
  InputProps={{
    classes: {
      root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
      focused: classes.cssFocused,
      notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
    }
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: You say it remains black, but in your example the actual label is always white, focussed or not. By 'label' do you mean the color of the input value?

Comment: @jagsler Yes. When i write the input is white and when the input loses focus it becoms black again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also set the default color of the root styles to white.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textField: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  cssLabel: {
    color: "white"
  },
  cssOutlinedInput: {
    color: 'white',   // <!-- ADD THIS ONE
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: `white !important`
    }
  },
  cssFocused: { color: "white !important" },

  notchedOutline: {
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderColor: "white !important"
  }
}));
```